# Prove that $OP, DK_A, EK_B, FK_C$ are concurrent

Tags: geometry

I am seeking a solution to the following problem. Thanks

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LWE9.png)

Telv Cohl: Given a △ABC inscribed in ⊙(O) and a point P. Let △DEF be the tangential triangle of △ABC and let $K_A, K_B, K_C$ be the symmedian point of △BPC, △CPA, △APB, respectively. Prove that $OP, DK_A, EK_B, FK_C$ are concurrent.

Notes:

It is easy to see the statement is true when P is on the circumcircle ⊙() since the four lines are concurrent at P. But I was not able to make any meaningful progress beyond that. One can switch to prove $Δ___$ and Δ are axially perspective due to Desargues's theorem. But I did not see it became any easier.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far to prove these lines are concurrent? What are your thoughts about the problem?

Comment: I believe it is an IMO level problem. I have not been able to prove it so far, and I could not find a solution any where. Thanks.

Comment: It is easy to see the statement is true when P is on the circumcircle $⊙(O)$ since the four lines are concurrent at P. But I was not able to make any meaningful progress beyond that. One can switch to prove $\Delta K_AK_BK_C$ and $\Delta DEF$ are axially perspective due to Desargues's theorem. But I did not see it became any easier.

Comment: It definitely seems like an interesting question. Can you add your last comment into the body of your question so that your question doesn't attract downvotes due to lack of attempt and trying?

Comment: Who or what is Telv Cohl ?

Comment: The author, I assume.